# How do I validate erate to two decimal places?

Tags: java

When I try to use the validation methods for erate it always comes up as invalid, how do I fix the validation method using the code I used inside the method.

```
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter employee hourly rate: ");
        while(checkEname(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only rate of two decimal places allowed! Re-enter employee hourly rate ");
        }//end while 
    erate = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

This is the validation methods called

```
    boolean checkErate(String input)
{
    int dotCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
         if(input.charAt(i) == '.')
                 dotCount++;
         else 
             if(!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)))
                 return false;
     if(dotCount !=1 )
         return false;
     else
         if(input.charAt(input.length() - 3) == '.')
             return true;
         else
             return false;
}//end checkErate
```

Comment: Try this, String [] erateSplit = input.split(".");, then check the length of erateSplit[1].

Comment: Try a regular expression. Note that I would find it rather annoying to always enter the decimals if the decimals could well be `00`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to check if the erate is a valid number.

Instead of doing the search for the decimal point, and evaluating it's position, what you can do instead is something like this:

```
String [] inputSplit = input.split(".");
if (inputSplit.length() >2) {
    return false;
}
if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", inputSplit[0]) == false ||  Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", inputSplit[1]) == false){
    return false;
}
```